# Could not determine type for: java.util.Set for Jpa/Neo4J Cross Store Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have a Jpa entity which also acts as a Neo4j cross store. Most of the fields in the entity are saved to Mysql database except the Collection 'followers', which is stored in Neo4j.  The problem is with the Collection 'followers'. it throws the exception "hibernate MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set".  A quick search yields a bunch of Jpa Related solutions (e.g. adding onetomany annotation to the field etc) which I assume is not relevant in this case because the collection is saved in Neo4j not Mysql.

```
Stacktrace
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: game, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(followers)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:469)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1303)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1761)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    ... 16 more

-------
@Entity
@Table(name="game")
@NodeEntity(partial = true)
public class Game implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @RelatedTo(type="GAME", direction=Direction.INCOMING, elementClass = Account.class)     
    @Fetch


@GraphProperty
    private Set<Account> followers = new HashSet<Account>();



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="game_id")
    private Long gameId;
    @Column(name="name",unique=true)
    private String name;    
....

    //Accessors

    public Long getGameId() {
        return gameId;
    }



    public void setGameId(Long gameId) {
        this.gameId = gameId;
    }
...
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "...";
    }



}



//Jpa Setup

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableJpaRepositories(value={"com.repository"}, entityManagerFactoryRef="entityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef="transactionManager")
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
public class JpaConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() { 
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager(); 
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory((EntityManagerFactory) entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager; 
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {      
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.core");
        factory.setJpaPropertyMap(AppUtil.jpaProperties());
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return factory; 
    }


        @Bean
        public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource(){    
            DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
            driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
            driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
            driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));      
            return driverManagerDataSource;
        }


    }

//Neo4j Setup
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"..."})
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(value={"..."})
public class Neo4JConfig extends CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration{

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    @Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public SpringRestGraphDatabase graphDatabaseService(){
        SpringRestGraphDatabase springRestGraphDatabase = new SpringRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
        return springRestGraphDatabase;

    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate(){
        return new Neo4jTemplate((GraphDatabase) graphDatabaseService());
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jMappingContext neo4jMappingContext() {
        return new Neo4jMappingContext();
    }

}
```

I have uploaded a project to simulate the following problem.  Download and run AccountTester.class to see Exception - http://filebin.ca/1PgiysEBAG4Q/CrossStore.zip.

Comment: It seems you have a configuration problem as Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) should be driving the persistence and its aspect should make the SDN-annotated-field transient for JPA...

Have you tried fully persisting another entity to Neo4j?

Comment: Same for all Entities. updated post with a Neo4J Config Settings

Comment: whether you are going to save it using Neo4j API or not is not of importance; it is marked as an Entity and so its visible to Hibernate (unless you restrict that in the persistence.xml via exclude-unlisted-classes). If it is visible to Hibernate then they seem to need OneToMany etc specifying (though it has to be said that some JPA implementations don't insist on that, since things can be determined from the field type).

Comment: Well, that's why you need to tell SDN there is an JPA EntityManager so its aspect can intercept all persistence calls before delegating to JPA... See my answer below.